# why is my funtion within componentDidMount() completely ignored?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is the function of setting the side draw to false ignored when I can get the exact same function to work on click? I can even get the componentDidMount to console.log what is happening? I have been trying different ways to get it to work componentWillunmount etc but nothing other than onclick seems to work with it any thoughts?

```
export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: false
  };


  drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  };

  sidedrawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
  }

  backdropClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    let backdrop;
    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />
    }


    return (
      <div className="App_margin">
        <Router>
          <div className='App'>
            <Nav drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
            <SideDrawer  sidedrawerClickHandler={this.sidedrawerToggleClickHandler}  show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
              { backdrop }
              < Switch >
              <Route path='/setup_page' component={setup_page} exact />
              <Route path='/main_page' component={main_page} />
              <Route path='/settings_page' component={settings_page} />
              <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: correction console.log isn't working either unsure why I thought it did, I think its because this code on my other project works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect this to do - `sideDrawOpen` is initialised as `false` so setting it as that in `componentDidMount` won't change anything.

Comment: 'componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ done: true });
    }, 2000);
  }'

Comment: @LawrenceWitt upon a click function the side drawer is set to true where links can be clicked currently new components mount and the side drawer state stays as true(tested using the react chrome extension) i want it to set to false when these links are clicked so the side draw closes when a new route is rendered

Answer (score 2):

Your state is initializing with `state = { sideDrawerOpen: false }`. When you run the `componentDidMount()` function you are trying to set `this.state.sideDrawerOpen` to false. The state is not changing, therefore there are no updates.

Since you are already initializing the `sideDrawerOpen` property to false, there is no need to set it to false again upon component mount.

Comment: Thanks I understand that but what I'm using this for is a side draw so on start I want it to be set to false when a new component mounts the DOM using the links in the side drawer i'd like the side draw to close as its current state is true. any way to do this? my code currently works for this 'let backdrop;
    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />
    }'

Comment: You need to pass props into the component that handles the `sideDrawerOpen` state and handle those props with `componentDidUpdate()`.

Lets say you have a `Dashboard` component that handles mounting component views. Every time you click on a link to open a new view in the `Dashboard`, you need to pass in a `true or false` prop into your Side Drawer that tells it to open or close.

Comment: but sidedrawopen is handled within this page? for instance  'let backdrop;
    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />
    }' works this is why I'm confused or do I need to to pass props of componentwillunmount from the other components?

Answer (score 0):

Your `componetsDidMount()` is completely useless and your code is OK if you remove it.